# How to add devices to iTunesConnect and send IPA packed app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I need to send an iphone app for testing to a remote customer. How can I add the UDIDs and pack the IPA so they can drop in iTunes & sync to test it?

Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend checkout testflightapp.com for this. It's much easier.  However,  if you have to do this, you have to add the device ids in itunesconnect to the provisioning profile, then re-download that profile and build/sign the app with that profile. You can then build and archive and then use the Organizer to save the archive to an IPA.

But really, use testflight.

Comment: using testflight - don't you need to create a provisioning profile and add team device ids anyway? by chance I've just registered there and looking how to start :)

Comment: You do need to add the device IDs to the provisioning profile but testflight automates a lot of the hard work (like installing on the testers device, getting their ID, etc).

Comment: Wow! testflight is truly amazing. Ty Joshua!